# Auto-login to console as root - no Xserver

Tags: automation, login, command-line, root

I'm setting up a PC for a very specific purpose. It's going to do some stuff deep underwater... round about 3km. We don't fear fish hijacking the box locally ;).

I'm trying to set up a login: no Xserver. Works well... I edited gdm.conf not to start. Great: that's how Linux is supposed to be in the first place.

Now my next and last task is: get the login. I googled upstart, event.d - my 10.4 distribution I recently installed doesn't have this or it doesn't work like I expect. I want the box to boot and to provide a local root shell. Just that...

How is this possible?

edit: 
possible tags: headless, auto-login. Can't set that....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want the box to start up with a root console, why running login in the first place?  You can bypass it and just start a shell on any TTY.

Programs running on the text consoles `tty1` to `tty6` are configured in the files `/etc/init/ttyX.conf`.  Now, the [getty](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/8/getty) program accepts a `-l` option to specify a program to start (default in `/bin/login`) - you can specify `/bin/sh` instead, and get a root shell. You need to give the `-n` option as well, to prevent *getty* from prompting for the user name.

Wrapping up: edit `/etc/init/tty1.conf` and replace the `exec /sbin/getty ...` line with:

```
exec /sbin/getty -n -l /bin/sh -8 38400 tty1
```

Same for tty2, tty3, ...

Comment: I suggest /bin/bash, dash is almost unusable from command line.

Comment: how do you automatically load `.bashrc` while auto login?

Comment: @c2h2: the `.bashrc` file is loaded by the bash shell itself -- irrespective of whether the login was automatic or not. (Actually, `bash` reads `.bash_login` and `.profile` files when it's a login shell, and `.bashrc` if it's *not* a login shell.)

Comment: ok thanks, but it seems i followed you methods, but PATH and various other settings are not loaded automatically.

Answer (score 1):

To actually enable root logins, you have to set a password for the root account and then unlock the locked root account. If you don't set a password for the root account the passwd command will return

```
passwd: unlocking the password would result in a passwordless account.
```

So, first execute in a terminal:

```
sudo passwd root
```

you will prompted for a new Unix password. Write it twice(second for confirmation).
Then execute:

```
sudo passwd -u root
```

to unlock the account. This should return

```
passwd: password expiry information changed
```

### Reverting back

If you want to disable root account in Ubuntu you need to lock the root account by using the following command:

```
sudo passwd -l root
```

Second:

Open the terminal and type:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/ect/lightdm/lightdm.config
```

(Orignal ) this it what it should already look like

```
SeatDefaults] 
greeter-session=unity-greeter          
user-session=unity                         
greeter-show-manual-login=true 
greeter-show-manual-login=true
```

(What you need to replace the original with)

```
[SeatDefaults] 
autologin-user=<YOUR USER> 
autologin-user-timeout=0 
user-session=ubuntu 
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

Comment: The OP stated clearly "no X11".