# Start with interactive console shell

Tags: boot, keyboard, root, console

This is a follow up question to [my prior thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8467/auto-login-to-console-as-root-no-xserver).
This solution works very well. However, after booting up, I only see a blinking cursor. <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>FX</kbd>, where X=1..4 e.g. invokes a root Shell. I want this Shell to be there after the initial bootup, without having to invoke further keystrokes.

Problem is: we have an "automated keyboard" controller that just types. If it doesn't have a shell, its input is lost :) 
I know that this is a very specific problem... so I'm extra happy for any answer I get.

Thanks in advance,
wishi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your previous post you say "I edited gdm.conf not to start.".

I think it can depend on how you modified that file, it is possible that you happen to go to the tty7 where gdm would start the X server, but without the X server started, so you have to change console to go to, say, tty1.

If you do not use it, it should be better to remove the `gdm` package.