# ubuntu with no gnome-desktop autologin and fullscreen chromium

Tags: 12.04, chromium, auto-login, kiosk

I'd like to achieve following:

1. no gnome-desktop
2. auto login a user and load .bashrc
3. auto startx and run my custom chromium

Now:

1. I'm able to start with text only, by adding `"text"` into `/etc/default/grub`
2. I'm able to login root, by editing `/etc/init/tty1.conf` (ref1) 
   but how to login as another user? say 'ubuntu' user and successfully load `.bashrc`?
3. how to auto invoke my app I am running after step2 login?

ref1: [Auto-login to console as root - no Xserver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8467/auto-login-to-console-as-root-no-xserver)

Answer (score 1):

Install "Slim" desktop manager.
Download for the Ubuntu Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

Or Install with the Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install slim
```

Slim can automatically login a user. Just change `/etc/slim.conf` [as described here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SLiM#Autologin).

Slim then starts all services in `.xinitrc` which lies in the home directory of the user that automatically logged in, e.g., `/home/some_user/.xinitrc`.

In this file you just put the line:

```
chromium
```

That should be all.